# How to fix this sql exeption

Tags: java, mysql

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <%
    ResultSet res = null;
        String username = request.getParameter("username");
        session.putValue("username", username);
        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        java.sql.Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ringcenter", "root", "");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String data = "select * from customer where username like ='%" + username + "%'";

        res = stat.executeQuery(data);
        if (res.last()) {
            if (res.getString(2).equals(password)) {
                out.print("Ok");
                response.sendRedirect("HomeCustomer.html");
            } else {
                response.sendRedirect("error.html");
            }
        } else
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

i have already made the registration page and it is working all the data i enters is saved in the database now i want to make a login page so i can retrieve the data i have stored in the database then i can login to the website as a user i have been try to do this but it gave me this error.

Comment: Side comment: concatenating query strings like that may leave your code vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should consider using a `PreparedStatement` instead.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '='%admin%'' at line 1

Comment: Something like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Group Assignment

remove the equal symbol ( = ) next to like.

try this query "select * from customer where username like '%" + username + "%'";

when using "like", no "=" symbol is needed.

Comment: @GroupAssignment,  1. first of all it's not a good idea to have SQL connection inside JSP, move your SQL  related code to a bean class.  2. In this particular case, Connection is not closed, you will end up connection issue soon. 3.  "else" block code is incomplete.   4. for code readability, use Column Name in res.getString() method, instead of Column Index.  5. Since it's a login page, there won't be multiple users for the same username in the DB, so don't use like , rather use "select * from customer where username =  " + username + "